# Is Ethereum a DAO?

Tags: dapps, dao

I am currently reading [the book Token Economy](https://shermin.net/token-economy-book/) from Shermin Voshmgir, which I am finding a very comprehensive overview of the current state of the Web3. I am still very new to the topic though, so bare with me if my terminology is inaccurate.

I find one of the given definitions in the book quite puzzling, namely the one for DAO:

> A DAOs represents a dynamic network governed by machine-enforceable protocols. They promise more decentralized and spontaneous coordination over the Internet between users who do not know or trust each other.

> DAOs are usually formalized by Smart Contracts.

But isn't this very similar to what a consensus protocol and a distributed ledger achieve? They provide a mean for actors that don't trust each others to join and participate to a network with specific economy/dynamics. To me this sounds the same objective with two different names.

So in a way, I wouldn't see much difference between a Smart Contract and a Consensus Mechanism, let aside the purely technical aspect. Likewise: Ethereum could be a DAO in an of itself.

Can someone please tell me what is the difference then? Or are Smart Contracts actually a DAO inception?

Answer (score 0):

Ethereum is not DAO, because its native token, ETH, is not used in governance.

Furthermore, consensus protocol and a distributed ledger achieve technical finality of a transaction. DAOs achieve governance of an organisation. They are very separate concerns.

Comment: Given the definition the original poster included, a "native token" isn't required for an organization to be labeled a DAO. Hence, your answer is invalid.

Comment: The definition given by Mr Voshmgir is bad. It is not aligned with DAOs are understood as today.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa where does your definition come from? I would like to read about it

Comment: You can e.g. read [industry news sources about DAOs](https://cointelegraph.com/search?query=dao)

Comment: Another long list of DAOs https://snapshot.page/#/